# Non-factorizable graphs in which every edge can be extended to a maximum matching

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

All graphs in this question are finite, simple, undirected, and unweighted. A graph is said to be *factorizable* if has a **perfect** matching, and *non-factorizable* otherwise. An edge in a graph is said to be *allowed* if it belongs to some **maximum** matching of the graph. Call a graph $G$ *permissive*<sup>1</sup> if *every* edge of $G$ is allowed.

I am interested in the properties of *non-factorizable* permissive graphs. What do we know about these? Where can I read up more on such graphs?

I could find quite a bit of existing work, both structural [1, 2] and algorithmic [3], on *factorizable* permissive graphs, which are called *matching-covered* graphs in the literature. However, I could not find anything at all about the case when every edge of a graph belongs to some maximum matching of the graph, and the graph itself does *not* have a perfect matching. What properties do such graphs have? Do we know something about their structure?

[1] [On the structure of factorizable graphs. Lovasz, 1972.](http://www.akademiai.com/index/u257n5n54n98071u.pdf)

[2] [Extending matchings in graphs: A survey. Plummer, 1994](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9200485A)

[3] [An $O(VE)$ algorithm for ear decompositions of matching-covered graphs. de Carvalho and Cheriyan, 2005](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1103969)

---

<sup>1</sup> My terminology, not standard.

Comment: What do you call a maximum matching? I have seen this terminology to describe matchings of a graph that cannot be extended with another edge. In this case, any matching is a subset of a maximal matching in a finite graph, and in particular every edge belongs to a maximal matching.

Comment: @zarathustra: "matchings of a graph that cannot be extended with another edge" are called maxi**mal** matchings, as you yourself do in your second sentence.  A maxi**mum** matching (in a graph without weights, as are those in my question) is a matching of the largest size. I am interested in edges which belong to maxim**mum** matchings and not just those which belong to maxi**mal** matchings; these latter are, as you pointed out, not very interesting.

Comment: My bad, I really should have thought about this for some more seconds before posting this silly comment.

Answer (score 2):

The [the Edmonds-Gallai decomposition](http://www.sfu.ca/~mdevos/notes/misc/gallai-edmonds.pdf) could be what you're looking for.  It decomposes a graph into sets $A$, $B$ and $C$, where $A$ is all the vertices missed by at least one maximum matching, $B = N(A)$, and $C$ is all other vertices.  Basically, every maximum matching matches vertices in $B$ to odd components of $G - B$ in $A$.   In $G - B$, $C$ consists of even components with perfect matchings.

If you follow what this means for a permissive graph, $B$ must be an independent set, since such edges must not be used in a maximum matching.  Furthermore, there are no edges from $C$ to the rest of the graph (so if we assume $G$ is connected, $C$ is empty).   That's quite a bit of structure right there.  I believe the components of $A$ are automatically permissive, and that any of the edges from $A$ to $B$ can automatically be used in maximum matchings, but I'm not sure.

---

Edit:  I noticed the Lovasz article you cite basically makes the same points I was making above, so you may have been aware of this information.  But regardless quite a bit is known about such graphs.

Comment: The components of $A$ are factor-critical (remove any vertex from a component, and the rest of the component has a perfect matching), which implies both that we may use any matching of $B$ into $A$ in a maximum matching of $G$, and that the components of $A$ are permissive.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, my question arose in fact from observing that graphs for which (i) part $C$ of the Gallai-Edmonds decomposition is empty and (ii) part $B$ is independent, are permissive; my question was prompted by my inability to find any more properties of such graphs. I guess I should have stated this in my question.

Comment: Also: that any edge from $A$ to $B$ can be used in a maximum matching follows directly from the definition of a permissive graph.  And as @GregoryJ.Puleo observed, since deleting any one vertex from a component $H$ of $A$ results in a subgraph $H'$ with a perfect matching, deleting an additional vertex from $H'$ gives us a subgraph $H''$ whose matching size is exactly one less than that of $H$. In particular this implies that the component $A$ is also permissive.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem can be reduced to just looking at matching-covered graphs. Let $G$ be a graph and let $\mu$ be its matching number. Let $S$ be the set of all vertices covered by all maximum matchings. Let $G'$ be the larger graph obtained by adding a new independent set of size $|V(G)| - 2\mu$, adjacent to the vertices of $V(G)-S$.

If $G'$ is well-covered, then $G$ is permissive: given any $e \in E(G)$, we can extend to a perfect matching in $G'$, whose restriction to $G$ must be a matching of size $\mu$. On the other hand, if $G$ is permissive then $G'$ is well-covered: given any $e \in E(G')$, either $e \in E(G)$ in which case we can use permissiveness to extend to a maximum $G$-matching and then fix the leftover vertices with the independent set, or else $e$ joins some $v \in V(G) - S$ to the independent set, in which case we can take some maximum $G$-matching that misses $v$ and fix the leftovers (necessarily including $v$) with the independent set, using the edge $e$.

Using this trick, you can probably "transfer" results about matching-covered graphs to your context.

Comment: Thank you. To rephrase what you said using the terminology of the question: Let $G,\mu,S$ be as in your answer. We construct $G'$ by adding an independent set of vertices, call it $T$, of size $|V(G)|-2\mu$ to $G$ and then adding all possible edges between $T$ and $V(G)\setminus{S}$. Now $G'$ has a perfect matching: take any maximum matching of $G$, and match the leftover vertices with vertices in $T$. The fact you prove is that $G'$ is permissive if and only if $G$ is permissive. This construction is probably the reason why nobody cares about permissive graphs without perfect matchings.!